# JQuery pop up/ alert needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dhtml

I have a list of elements that need to have a corresponding pop up for each element.  This is not a pop up where the background is blacked.  This is more like a javascript alert although I need to create my own styled button within the pop up with our own bespoke event assigned to it.  I need each pop to position itself appropriately next to the relevant item within the UI.

Whats the best way to do this?  Are there any examples please?  I only want the pop up to show when the visitor triggers an event.

Many thanks,

Comment: Try http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/

Comment: JQuery ui dialog, qtip2 - hundreds out there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this without using jQuery Plugins.

I put together a little [example](http://jsfiddle.net/eauur/1/).

Comment: thanks for the example.  How would that work if I need a button within the popup?  just thinking because it uses the data-popup attribute it's not ideal for the value of the data-popup to have html in it to create the button

Comment: Well, where would you like to get the contents for the popup from? Could they be in a hidden div somewhere in the DOM? Or, if you stay with the solution i proposed, maybe we could pass a parameter that changes where the button points to or something. I can edit the example if you let me know what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) for pop-up systems. Fırst of all; it is easy to learn and use.

And most importantly: [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) won't create conflicts with your other plugins (sometimes [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) does that).

Some Features:

- Supports photos, grouping, slideshow, ajax, inline, and iframed
  content.
- Lightweight: 10KB of JavaScript (less than 5KBs gzipped).
- Appearance is controlled through CSS so it can be restyled.

Comment: thanks for this although this is a modal window that darkens the background which I don't want.

Comment: you can change everthing with whatever you want, like this example: bbcnordic.com/london-calling/#!/about Just need to change css and background pictures inside colorbox folder.

Answer (score 0):

What about http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation
or http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message