# popup for asp.net application

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui

I am working on an asp.net application and I need a popup like this:

http://www.popupdomination.com/demo/

Is it some jquery plugin or what. Can this be used with asp.net page ? I need to show it on all pages. Pages have a common master page.

I know ajaxtoolkit has a modal control but I need like this. Please suggest

Regards,
Asif

Comment: Take a look at : http://www.jquerypopup.com/

Comment: you can use external plugin too: [colorbox,](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) reasons = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718363/jquery-pop-up-alert-needed/11718453#11718453

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick responses. but both these plugins close when i click otside popup, I dont want the popups to be closed like this. I want the popup to be closed by close/cross sign.

Comment: Dude you can customise this plugin's css whatever you like. If you want; you can put a **huge plus** too.

Comment: that website's pop-up plugin http://www.popupdomination.com/demo/lightbox-preview.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET does not support any popups, neither do any other language such as PHP. In short ASP.NET does not have messageboxes or dialogs. Note that ASP page is rendered inside web browser.

What is close that produces popups is JavaScript. But JavaScript popups are really simple and then they cannot be formatted.

Here the popup is actually a Div that simulates a popup. Styles are applied through JavaScript to create a popup dialog effect.

```
<div class="lightbox-top">
    <div class="lightbox-top-content">
    <p class="heading">Get my FREE 7 day fitness eCourse</p>

    <div class="bullet-listx">
       <ul class="bullet-list">                        
       <li>Achieve Ultimate fitness level</li>                        
       <li>Attract beautiful women</li>                        
       <li>Just two hours of "work" per day</li>                        
       <li>Get the body you want</li>                    
       </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
</div>
    </div>
```